# std::function implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel

I've decided to make an implementation of the C++11 class `function`. I was checking that I have done everything correctly and have not missed anything:

```
template < typename > class function;

template < typename _Ret, typename... _Args > class function<_Ret(_Args...)>
{
public:
    typedef _Ret result_type;
    typedef function<result_type(_Args...)> _Myt;
    typedef result_type(*pointer)(_Args...);

    function()
        : _f_ptr(nullptr)
    {
    }

    template < typename _Fn_Ty > function(_Fn_Ty &&_Fn)
        : _f_ptr(reinterpret_cast<pointer>(_Fn))
    {
    }

    function(pointer &&_Fn)
        : _f_ptr(_Fn)
    {
    }

    function(const _Myt &_Rhs)
        : _f_ptr(_Rhs.f_ptr)
    {
    }

    function(_Myt &&_Rhs)
        : _f_ptr(_Rhs.f_ptr)
    {
    }

    ~function()
    {
    }

    _Myt &assign(pointer &&_Fn)
    {
        _f_ptr = _Fn;
        return *this;
    }

    _Myt &operator=(pointer &&_Fn)
    {
        return assign(_Fn);
    }

    template < typename _Fn_Ty > _Myt &assign(_Fn_Ty &&_Fn)
    {
        _f_ptr = reinterpret_cast<pointer>(_Fn);
        return *this;
    }

    template < typename _Fn_Ty > _Myt &operator=(_Fn_Ty &&_Fn)
    {
        return assign<_Fn_Ty>(_Fn);
    }

    result_type operator()(_Args... _Arguments)
    {
        if (_f_ptr == nullptr)
        {
            throw std::exception("nullptr found instead of function");
        }
        return _f_ptr(_Arguments...);
    }

    pointer &ptr() const
    {
        return _f_ptr;
    }

    operator pointer &() const
{
    return _f_ptr;
}
private:
    pointer _f_ptr;
};
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide a compilable online example where you use your `function` to store (and then run) a function pointer, a pointer-to-member-function, a stateless lambda, a stateful lambda and a `bind` expression? [Look here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for inspiration.

Comment: In every one of your questions you use reserved identifiers and some people have commented on it yet you still do it. Is the habit too strong to break?

Comment: @Rapptz - I've kind of got used to it even though it is a bad habit. Woops :O

Comment: another recurring theme in your questions here: you like reimplementing Standard Library functionality, which is a great learning tool. But it would be better if you first carefully checked things like all member functions and their signatures against the Standard before posting Code to Review. That, better naming and a few test cases to show that your implementation has at least *a chance* of being correct, would go a long way for people to review your code more carefully. That's why online compilers exist!

Comment: This doesn't compile when testing with basic lambdas, like `function<int(int)> f = [](int i) -> int { return i * 2; };`

Comment: Since you don't seem to pay any attention to the advice we give you (and continue to create usable code) I see little point in bothering to review this code.

Comment: @LokiAstari - When you mean 'you don't seem to pay any attention to the advice we give you (and continue to create usable code)' - does that mean reserved identifiers? If so, it's a habit I got into, but I promise I will try and stop

Comment: This is Code Review, not Test My Code For Me. You should post code that, to the best of your knowledge after a fair (read: any) attempt, passes tests for the functionality it purports to implement. That is how you do "_checking that I have done everything correctly and have not missed anything_". The point I see on this site is to review *how* you did it and whether there might be cases you didn't consider - not just to get other people to check *if* it works for very basic cases. It's important when writing library code to maintain a baseline of tests in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has no chance of working, because the only non-static data member of your `function<void(void)>` is a single pointer of type `void (*)(void)`. There's no room to store any other kind of functor.

In other words, you've implemented the concept of "function pointer wrapped in a struct", but you haven't implemented anything like `std::function` yet.